# onClick button event error in react-native

Tags: react-native

Render Error
[image]

*Here is my code:*

function Adddetails () {
set(ref(db, 'users/' + phone), {
phone: phone,
parent: parent
}).then(() => {
alert('data updated');
})
.catch((error) => {
alert(error);
});
};

[button design code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsPJr.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error displays, the components in react-native should always start with an uppercase.

in your case you are calling `<button/>`  which is not a react-native component.

therefore, it should be switched to `<Button />`

Comment: Hi Azzam Michael, thanks now can able to view Button , I changed to  <Button title='test' onClick={Adddetails}></Button>

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are confusing React concepts with React Native. In React Native we don't have HTML based `button`. Either use `Button` component imported from `react-native` or Use a `TouchableOpacity` from `react-native`.

Also if that `button` is your own component make sure it Starts with a Captial B `<Button/>`

Comment: `import { Button , TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'`

Comment: Thanks Suyash, now i changed to   <Button title='test' onClick={Adddetails}></Button> working fine.